# Como passar um texto como parâmetro para uma função JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parâmetros, funções

Preciso fazer uma função JavaScript e quero que ela receba os parâmetros em formato de texto:

Código HTML:

```
<button onClick="AlteraNome(Felipe)">Enviar Nome</button>
```

Código JavaScript:

```
function AlteraNome(nome){
   document.write(nome);
}
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço!

Comment: Suponho que você queira pegar o valor vindo de um `input` certo? Clique em [edit] e adicione seu form.

Comment: Ou se você quiser passar um texto fixo, pode colocá-lo entre apóstrofos (`onClick="AlteraNome('Felipe');"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se estás a tentar obter o nome aplicado ao botão no exemplo da tua pergunta, podes fazer isso utilizando `document.getElementById("meuBotao").innerText;` da seguinte maneira:

```js
function alteraNome() {
    // procura o id="meuBotao" e substitui o texto dentro dele por - "Outro Nome Aqui"
    document.getElementById("meuBotao").innerText="Outro Nome Aqui";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alteraNome()" id="meuBotao">Altera Nome do Botão</button>
```

Se estás a tentar pegar um nome introduzido num `input` e passá-lo para outro lado qualquer, como uma outra `div` por exemplo, podes fazê-lo da seguinte maneira:

```js
function transfereNome() {
    var input = document.getElementById('enviaNome')
    var div = document.getElementById('mostraNome');
    // diz que o conteúdo dentro do id="mostraNome" é igual ao valor introduzido no input
    div.innerText = input.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="enviaNome"/>
<button onclick="transfereNome()">Enviar Nome</button>
<div id="mostraNome"></div>
```

Comment: Nota: esses exemplos não funcionam no Firefox < 45 (`innerText` não é suportado). Você *poderia* usar `textContent`, mas o mesmo não funciona no IE < 9, e faz coisas "estranhas" com os espaços em branco. Ver [esse post](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/) (em inglês) pra mais detalhes.